# Clear input of type textbox only

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In my asp.net application, I'm using jquery to clear the contents of textboxes in my form. I'm currently using this code to do this:

```
 $('#FillForm input').val(function () {
       return '';
});
```

This code clears textboxes well but it also clears the buttons I have on the forms -it sort of flashes the value since the default button name returns once again- but i don't want this to happen, I won't to clear the value for the input textboxes only, I'm looking for something like this:

```
 $('#FillForm input.textbox').val(function () {
                    return '';
                });
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As an aside... `.val('');` == `.val(function(){ return ''; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('#FillForm input[type=text]').val(function () {
```

In fact why do you even need that closure?

```
 $('#FillForm input[type=text]').val('');  // that's all you need
```

**[RTFM](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)**

Comment: I was just going to ask you why does the syntax doesn't have a closing bracket for 'input[type=text' but then I see you've added it. However, it's very strange that although I copy-pasted your text (with the missing bracket) it worked !!

Comment: yep it was only a typo, not intentional. Even if it worked without it, still place it cause that's the right syntax.

Comment: Yes, my problem is, how come it worked without the closing bracket!

Comment: Fault tolerance. don't rely on it :)

Comment: Oh I see. Now, i'm getting introduced to jquery!

Answer (score 1):

Remove text `on clicking the element:`

```
$('#FillForm input:text').click(
function(){
    $(this).val('');
});
```

OR

```
$('#FillForm input:text').val('');
```